# optirun "Could not enable discrete graphics card" despite setting driver to nviia-current

Tags: graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I've been trying to set up optirun/primusrun for about a day now, and can't get past the part where I test optirun/primusrun glxgears. Both return an error "Could not enable discrete graphics card" even though I set the driver to nvidia-current in the config file. Can anyone help with this?

I am using Ubuntu 21.04 on a Dell XPS 7590. The only reason I'm doing this is because steam kept setting the default display adapter to the iGPU.

Comment: You need to install the recommended Nvidia drivers version for your card and that, definitely, isn't `nvidia-current`.

Comment: Ubuntu-drivers installed 460, which is currently the latest release. Should I specify nvidia-460 instead of nvidia-current?